# Create string illimitate in java android

Tags: java, android, string

I'm sorry, i didn't have any code for the moment but i need help.

**My android application :**
In a string-array, i have a lot of sentences (declared on a .xml file).

**In my android application i want this :** User can create her sentences *(illimitate)* and stock it in xml file.

How can i make a function who add somes sentences to a .xml file.

If it's not possible, how can i make it

Exemple :
In my app, i have :

```
    <string-array name="MyStringArra1">
        <item>My Sentence 1</item>
        <item>My Sentence 2</item>
</string-array>
```

And if user add : Sentence 3, i want put it in this file.

Comment: So you want to modify your App resorces?

Comment: Yes. I want add elements to `"MyStringArray_user"` when he add sentences

Comment: @AlexFrasure If i'm guessing correctly you wanna add/store extra sentences in a resource file, for each user / install individually?

If so, there's a problem. The files under resources are meant to be read-only. You can however try other datastores in the Android ecosystem. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html would be a great place to start. Just read another file from storage in `onStart` etc and in `onStop` write all the new lines to that same file.

Comment: @MrKickkiller Ok, thank you for this documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify *resource* files from your Android application as they are compiled into your app, and therefore don't even exist on your device. If you want your user to be able to insert/edit/remove strings from a list, you must use a database or [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

The following link guides you into creating a ToDo list application, which is basically a list of strings. [Starting Android Development, Creating a Todo App](https://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/)